# Pass dates between views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass dates/strings between two view but I don't know it.

**My code**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pasa_codigo"]) {
        Formulario *segundoView = [segue destinationViewController];
        segundoView.nombre = [input_codigo text];

   }
}
```

The error: "reason: '-[UIViewController setNombre:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Answer (score 0):

The `nombre` should be Property in `Formulario` class. And also you need to type cast the `[segue destinationViewController]` with your `Formulario` class.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pasa_codigo"]) {
        Formulario *segundoView = (Formulario *)[segue destinationViewController];
        segundoView.nombre = [input_codigo text];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is getting returned from `[seque destinationViewController];` is a `UIViewController` so try casting it. So replace with this `Formulario *sequndoView = (Formulario *)[seque destinationViewController];`

So because `[seque destinationViewController];` just returns a `UIViewController` when you try and do `segundoView.nombre = [input_codigo text]` it is trying to call the set on an instance of `UIViewController` but `UIViewController` doesn't have the property of `nombre` that is a property on `Formulario` so this is the reason for the type cast.

Answer (score 0):

**In IB change the class name UIViewController to Formulario**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pasa_codigo"]) {

        UIViewController *segundoView = [segue destinationViewController];

        if ([segundoView isKindOfClass:[Formulario class]) {

            segundoView.nombre = [input_codigo text];

        }else{
            //For Debugging print the view controller to know the name of the destination                
            NSLog(@"Which view controller is Destination : %@",segundoView);
        }


    }
}
```

Still you are facing the crash, then verify the "nombre" property was declared in Formulario.h file.

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *nombre;
```